# Playing audio from variable in React Native

Tags: android, audio, react-native, text-to-speech, watson

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to code a POC where I use the text-to-speech feature from Watson-IBM.

This service, from IBM, has an HTTP REST interface that I provide the text and it returns to me the .wav (for example) file with the audio of that text.

So, in a way, I have the "audio" saved in a variable.

Now I need to play this audio.

I've looked for some libraries that would play this audio. However, most of them need a "real file", with a path, to be able to play the audio.
However, in my case, I do not have a "real file" (by "real file", I mean a file in the folder of the project, for example). I have only a variable with this information.

I could save this variable to a file and then read from this file, but I am not sure if this is the best way to go.

So, can anyone suggest to me a library (or a better approach) to play this audio that came from Watson text-to-speech in my react native app?

(I need it to work only on Android. No need for iOS support.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [react-native-audio-toolkit](https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit) for playing network resources.

For Watson API Authentication, you could get [authentication token](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-tokens.html) then use it via `watson-token` query parameter.

```
import { Player } from 'react-native-audio-toolkit';

new Player('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?watson-token=TOKEN').play();
```

Watson API Doc: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/